# Adding a new language to the site using Spring Roo 2

Tags: spring-roo

I've create a site with Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3, when I try to add a language, it said :

```
roo> addon create i18n --topLevelPackage com.foo --locale fr
Command 'addon create i18n --topLevelPackage com.foo --locale fr' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)
```

So I've read Roo is provided with 6 languages, but it is said hust english and spanish are possible values.Maybe the version 2.0.0.M3 doesn't include other language.

```
roo> help web mvc language
SYNOPSIS 
     web mvc language [OPTIONS]

DESCRIPTION 
     Installs new language in generated project views. Also, could be used to 
     specify the default language of the project.

OPTIONS 
     --code    The language code for the desired bundle.Possible values are:
               supported languages. Currently `en` (English, default) and `es` (Spanish).
```

So the question is how I can add a language, like fr, with Roo 2.0.0.M3 ?

Answer (score 0):

The command `addon create i18n --topLevelPackage com.foo --locale fr` that you're trying to use could be used to create a new `i18n bundle`.

The generated bundle contains a `messages.properties` file that you should translate to the desired language. After that, you should include this `bundle` in the Spring Roo shell using the `addon install` command. With that, when you try to use the `web mvc language` command, the `--code` parameter will be autocomplete with the `es`, `en` code and with the language that you've created.

Sorry if the Spring Roo reference guide says that it's provided with 6 languages. I'll check that.

Hope it helps,

**NOTE**: Remember that the `addon create i18n --topLevelPackage com.foo --locale fr` command is only available if you didn't create an Spring Project before in the current folder.

Comment: Thank you for the information. But not available after creating the Spring project means that we should plan all supported languages before creating the project. In reality, we add a language during the project, not before. Starting with en, then add others languages after a while. Then if I try to change the language html dropdown file, and I start roo shell, it undone the changes in the file I edited, quite frustrating.

Comment: I think we need a clear explain how to create and add a language bundle in a spring-roo project, step by step. I try to create and add a bundle from a new directory, as explain in http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/simple-addons.html and http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/roo/94648-addon-create-i18n-does-not-work , but first the org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.jsp maven project for 2.0.0.M3 doesn't exists (so I used 2.0.0.M1), now I try to do an addon install url, but got some symbolic name problem...

Comment: Now I got an org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.jsp.i18n version error : 
`roo> addon install url --url file:///home/dams/roo/language_fr/target/com.foo.i18n.fr-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar`
`Bundle ID: 104`

`roo> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.foo.i18n.fr [104](R 104.0): missing requirement [com.foo.i18n.fr [104](R 104.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.jsp.i18n)(version>=2.0.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))`